# using html and javascript scroll page

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make my menu get fixed when my scroll page gets higher then 100px.
this my code . i would like some helps plis.

plis help isnt working.

my javascript isnt working has i excepted to work

```js
function init(){
    if(document.scrollTop > 50)
    {
        document.getElementById('menu1').classList.add = "menudeslizar";
        //im trying to replace the menu1 to menudeslizar class when scroll gets higher then 50.
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('menu1').classList.remove('menudeslizar');   
    }
}
window.onload = init();
```

```css
My css is fine . the menudeslizar is the class that i want to use when scroll down the page.

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body{
    height: 1200px;   
}
.menudeslizar {
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;  
}
#menu1 {
    height: 42px;
    background-color:#666;
}
.menu ul {   
    list-style: none;
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 12px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ACACAC;
}
.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: black;   
}
```

```html
<html lang="Pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <nav id="menu1">
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>    
                    <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Fix the menu to the screen?

Comment: yes . like this website let me show you http://gauged2.com/ scroll it down and look at menu bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you mean?(without any fancy animations etc.)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrgf9w5g/)  (added 200px free scrollroom at the top by using a div)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var origOffsetY = 200; /*sample 200px offset*/



    function scroll() {


        if ($(window).scrollTop() > origOffsetY) {
            $('#menu1').addClass('menudeslizar');
        } else {
            $('#menu1').removeClass('menudeslizar');
        }
    }

    document.onscroll = scroll;

});
```

You want to use document.onscroll so it will check the `window.scrollTop` everytime the user scrolls.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks alot man,your the best :). I just have a question why does everyone uses jquery instead of javascript? i

Comment: Np :) jQuery is a javascript library, this means that it adds properties you can use. It's very handy, check it out at their page: http://jquery.com/